# Equivalence of 2 simple parts of pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I am to implement an algorithm where the way I thought it out on paper is slightly different from the pseudo-code suggested in our text book. I am trying to convince myself that the 2 snippets of pseudo below will do the same thing without any major difference in order of time complexity when having to implement the 'contains' and generation of all subsets in respectively Two and One below. I am having trouble coming up with something rigorous that will convince me.

T and A are sets of subsets of a finite set I. No set or subset is empty and every set has a "field" called 'count'.

Snippet One:

```
For-each t in T do {
  A_t = A intersected with the set of all non-empty subsets of t
  For-each a in A_t do {
    a.count++
  }
}
```

Snippet Two:

```
For-each a in A do {
  a.count = count(a, T)
}
```

Here count is defined by

```
count(a, T) {
  c = 0
  For-each t in T do {
    if (t contains a) {
      c++
    }
return c
}
```

Comment: What does the contains function do?  Return true if t is a subset of a?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you implement your subset generation and contains function. My guess is that in most cases, generating all those subsets is not worth it and (as `a` is in `A_t` iff `a` is in `A` and in the set of subsets of `t`, i.e. `a` is in `A_t` iff `a` is in `A` and `t` contains `a`) you can just rewrite your first snippet to

```
For-each t in T do {
  For-each a in A do {
    if (t contains a){
      a.count++
    }
  }
}
```

while your second snippet is

```
For-each a in A do {
  For-each t in T do {
    if (t contains a){
      a.count++
    }
  }
}
```

(in both cases assuming that for all `a` in `A`, `a.count` is initially set to 0)